# How can can I develop a JFrame that has different parts of transparency

Tags: java, swing

Basically I don't know how to make a JFrame which has a 100% transparent center and is filled gray outside. I looked at the whole Internet how to do that. You should see the window behind this application or even it is possible to practically reach through that window.

What I have done so far was creating a transparent jframe, but then I tried to create a BufferedImage but after that I don't know how to subtract the area of a rectangle from the BufferedImage. So the center of the application is transparent.

Comment: Either use a partially transparent .png image or set the `Clip` of the `Graphics` context to the outer edge that should be drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know how to make a JFrame which has a 100% transparent center and is filled gray outside

Add a transparent panel with a `Border` to the transparent frame.

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, new Color(128, 128, 128, 64));
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setOpaque( false );
panel.setBorder( border );
frame.add( panel );
```